# Setting additional fields when creating a container with TRIM ServiceAPI

Tags: c#, .net, hp-trim

I have some code that creates a container in TRIM/HPRM/HPECM which looks like this:

```
TRIMService.Record preq = new TRIMService.Record() {
    Title = recordTitle,
    LongNumber = recordNumber,
    RecordType = new TRIMService.RecordTypeRef() { Uri = 12345 },
};
TRIMService.RecordsResponse pres = trim.Post<TRIMService.RecordsResponse>(preq);
```

I now need to set the value of a TRIM "additional field".  These are user-defined fields so values for them do not exist in the C# ServiceStack implementation for the TRIM ServiceAPI.

TRIM includes examples for this, but they are HTML based and simply submit the additional fields with their text names, but I can't do this in .NET as it's expecting a structure member rather than a string.

How does one go about setting these "additional fields" in C#.NET with the ServiceAPI?